How to publish "Angular and ASP.Net Core" template from VS2022
I am trying to deploy a sample .net8/Angular app that I created from the "Angular and ASP.Net Core" template provided by Visual Studio 2022 from GitLab to a CloudFoundry server.
However, I don't think the template is configured correctly, for the dotnet publish
The template creates two projects: MyTest.Server and mytest.client.
In my gitlab-ci.yml I am trying to execute the following commands:

dotnet restore ./*.sln
dotnet build -c Release .*.sln
dotnet publish MyTest.Server/MyTest.Server.csproj -c Release -o {$PWD}/publish

I see the client and server projects being built in the publish step

${PWD}/mytest.client/dist/mytest.client
MyTest.Server -> ${PWD}/publish/

But, when I deploy this to Cloud Foundry, while the back-end server starts up, according to the logs, it does not appear to be hosting the Angular app, as I get a 404 error when connecting to the URL.
Example error: No webpage was found for the web address: https://mytest.my-cloud-foundry-server.com (HTTP ERROR 404)
When I run from Visual Studio, everything starts up as expected, back-end runs, front-end starts with ng serve browser starts up and displays the page, etc.
Other than going back to the older ASP.Net/Angular template that I've been using since .net 3.1, through .net 6... I'm not sure what to do and not having much luck searching yet.
I am thinking this may be because the angular client is being published to a dist folder, while the publish is using a wwwroot/browser folder... but I don't see where that browser folder is being created...

when running locally the special "wwwroot" folder is in memory.  When publishing it'll create that directory (and any subs).  You might check this thread for a similar sounding problem/bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Angular-and-ASPNET-core-project-publis/10542516

The 'Angular and ASP.Net Core' project template available in Visual Studio 2022 currently defaults to Angular 15.
When updating Angular, there were changes involving @angular-devkit/build-angular:application introduced during Angular 17 that were meant to 'simplify' support of SSR and browser side applications. This change moved all angular client code into a 'browser' folder which broke every Angular app that does not use SSR.
In Dec 2023 a change was introduced to allow overriding this with a setting in the angular.json file:
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": {
          "base": "dist/your-app.client",
          "browser": ""              <------------- This line here
        },

